# PayPalPro Flow API and Address and Security Code Verification

Tags: .net, api, paypal

I am building an integration with PayPalPro Flow in .NET and wondering which fields do I need to use for Address verification and Security Code (PIN) verification or is this something you need to setup through PayPal Merchant interface when in Production.

Answer (score 0):

[PayPal's PayFlow documentation](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf) covers lots of information about address verification, including the individual parameters that are used for it.  Same with card code.

When you say "need to use", though, I'm not sure if you're asking about which ones are required (that you may want to leave out if you can) if you're asking what exactly you need to pass to get valid response codes back for AVS and CVV2..??

The first part of the equation is how your PayPal account was vetted and setup when you first signed up for Payments Pro (PayFlow).  Sometimes they give you full access to be able to leave billing address and card code parameters out of your request altogether, which of course would result in a failure response code coming back for both, but they leave it up to you as the merchant to decide how to handle that risk.

In other cases PayPal will approve your account, but they'll force you to include a billing address and card code, and if either fails, they would decline the payment.

I always recommend passing it anyway, in which case you'd use the billing address parameters and the card code parameters as outlined in their documentation.

The response you get back when you run the PayFlow request will include a CVV2MATCH and AVSADDR parameter which will have the code that was returned by the card issuing bank based on the details you passed in the request.  Again, the documentation outlines what codes are available and what they mean.